# Converting DXF to shapefile with custom attributes (color)

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, ogr

I am trying to convert .dxf to .shp with passing color attribute to entities in .shp. When using

```
ogrinfo -al test.dxf
```

I can see colors for line and text features:

```
OGRFeature(entities):13
  Layer (String) = SUKR_T_0
  SubClasses (String) = AcDbEntity:AcDbLine
  Linetype (String) = Continuous
  EntityHandle (String) = 3A
  Style = PEN(c:#000000)
  LINESTRING Z (7461676.72603719 5896543.45422807 0,7461679.3588753 5896543.45422807 0)

OGRFeature(entities):14
  Layer (String) = SUKR_T_0
  SubClasses (String) = AcDbEntity:AcDbText:AcDbText
  EntityHandle (String) = 3B
  Text (String) = 174.38
  Style = LABEL(f:"Arial",t:"174.38",p:4,a:323,s:0.75g,c:#000000)
  POINT Z (7461679.99522559 5896542.98530416 0)
```

as PEN and LABEL “c” value, respectively.

When converting texts with

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output_p.shp test.dxf -nlt Point -skipfailures
```

or lines with

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output_l.shp test.dxf -nlt LINESTRING -skipfailures
```

this value disappears in translation. Ideally for me would be just to create another attribute for every entity in .shp - “color”, and pass “c” value to this attribute. Is it possible in ogr2ogr command, or does it require some more effort ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use QGIS with a plugin AnotherDXFImporter. It is able to read the styles. You can import the dxf from the menu Vector/DXF import.

[image: dxf plugin]

Then you can export the layer from QGIS as a shapefile and the attribute table will have the colors.

[image: attribute table]